# Responsive Height/Width Video Header

Tags: css, html

I'm working on making a responsive html5 video header for a website, I would like it to respond vertically as well as horizontally, using CSS only for responsiveness.

`http://jsfiddle.net/b9cpmuy9` is what I'm using for responsive width (with a borrowed video from another post on here).

`width:100%;height:auto;` works for responsive width.

I tried `height:100%;width:auto;min-width:100%;` for responsive height, but it only works up until the full width of the source file, and when smaller only clips to the right. I would like it to remain centered and clip from left and right sides.

I'd like it to work like this: http://salleedesign.com/home, but with video. Can it be done?

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/x22r8her/1/ I've got something! The ONLY thing wrong with this that I can see is that when it gets small enough (width-wise) it starts clipping only on the right. Why is that?

Comment: Do you mean full window video?

Comment: Yes. It's container is `width:100vw;height:100vh;`

Comment: Do you want it to break the aspect ratio of the video too?

Comment: No, I would rather it clipped off at the edges of its container

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204932/video-height-and-width-for-responsive-website/41811314#41811314

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML elements are left and top aligned. What you could do is to expand the container to a large size and use `margin: auto`

Example CSS:

```
video {
    position:absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    bottom: -99999px;
    left: -99999px;
    right: -99999px;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:50%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mLnsbyk1/